# Помогите решить небольшую задачу

Tags: python, task

Написать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя число, после этого выводит строку типа: 2 компьютера. В зависимости от введенного числа, программа должна корректно подставлять окончание для слово компьютер.

!Код должен быть на языке python!

Comment: Люди не любят, когда их просят о помощи в форме повелительного наклонения. Приложите усилия к решению самостоятельно и опишите конкретную проблему, с которой столкнулись при попытке решить. В ином случае, обратитесь за решением на фриланс биржу.

Comment: Учебное задание без попыток решить самостоятельно

Answer (score 1):

правило такое:

3 формы - 1) мячик, 2) мячика, 3) мячиков

1. если последние 2 цифры числа от 11 до 19 - то используется 3 форма
2. если последняя цифра 1 - 1 форма
3. если последняя цифра от 2 до 4 - 2 форма
4. во всех остальных случаях - 3 форма

Получить нужные числа/цифры можно определением остатка от деления числа на 10 и 100. Для этого используем `%`

Получить число от пользователя можно через `input()`

Преобразовать его (ибо введена будет строка) в число - через `int()`

Ну и дальше вам понадобится `if elif else` конструкция

Comment: Что за "цифры"?

Comment: 10 <= x <= 20 or (x%10) in [0,5,6,7,8,9]:  -> 'ов'  (x%10) mod in [2,3,4] -> 'а' т.е достаточно одной цифры и сравнения числа с диапазоном

Comment: Виктор как будете работать с числом `112`? ;-)

Comment: ну не учёл этот вариант:)

Comment: Можно код,который иллюстрирует данный пример?

Comment: @Zender Вам же алгоритм дали, куски кода в комментариях есть, осталось добавить 10 <= (x%100) <= 20

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите

```
number = int(input("Введите количество компьютеров:"))
print(f'{number} Компьютеров')
```

Comment: А если пользователь ввсед 1? То будет "1 Компьютеров" ?